# Convert simple code from JS to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm new at both JS and jQuery (behind the times I know) but I have a working JS function that is very simple that I'd like to convert to jQuery.  I think if I can get help with this it will help me in understanding the mechanics of jQuery (as I understand this JS).

What this does is to show or hide a div based on whether a pair of radio buttons are selected Yes or no.  What I'd like to do (on load) is slide the div in if Yes is selected and out if No is selected.  I'd like no to be default (right now Yes is default).  I do have jQueryUI running for the slide.

Here is the JS code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function makeChoice()
{
    if (document.form1.mobileyesno[1].checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById('wanttexts').style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
        }
    else
        {
            document.getElementById('wanttexts').style.visibility = 'visible';          
        }
}

</script>
```

I know this is probably elementary but I need the help. :-)  Thanks!

Comment: Paste your html, better yet, start a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    if ($('input[name="mobileyesno"]:checked').val() == 'Yes') {
      $('#wanttexts').show();
    } else {
      $('#wanttexts').hide();
    }
);
```

The outer `$(function() { });` means that the code in the curly brackets will run when the page has finished loading. `$('input[name="mobileyesno"]:checked')` is a way of selecting all input fields which have the name "mobileyesno" and are currently checked, and `val()` extracts the value of that input field. If you want a particular input field to be selected by default when the page loads, add the `checked="checked"` attribute to the input tag for that radio button.

Answer (score 3):

```
function makeChoice() {
    $('#wanttexts').css(
        'visibility',
        document.form1.mobileyesno[1].checked ? 'hidden' : 'visible'
    );
}
```

EDIT better yet:

```
function makeChoice() {
    $('#wanttexts')
        [document.form1.mobileyesno[1].checked ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']();
}
```

Comment: @ShankarSangoli: Try it out, you may be suprised

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `jQuery` then you can try this

```
function makeChoice()
{
    if (document.form1.mobileyesno[1].checked == true)
        {
            $('#wanttexts').slideDown(); 
        }
    else
        {
            $('#wanttexts').slideUp();          
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I could just give you some code converting it for you, but that wouldn't really help. ;) Here's some links I would start with to replace things in that function specifically. The jQuery docs are actually really great (most of the time).

- [Selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), specifically, [ID Selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). So this is how you actually reference a specific set of things.
- [CSS](http://api.jquery.com/css/) This is the function you use to change CSS on an element. Here's the broader section for how to [change things in the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/).
- For checked, you should use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/). There's actually been some recent upheaval about the difference between that and [.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), but don't worry about it too much.
- To do something on load, you should look at [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/). You can pass functions in that for the whole document like this:

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //stuff to do on load
});
```

- To show or hide things in jQuery, it actually has some convenience functions like [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), but you can look at [effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/) for more things like sliding and fading. Pretty neat stuff.

There's some other things to know about jQuery, like that you can chain things, etc. It would be worth it to go through some of the introductory documentation like [this](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works).

Answer (score 0):

```
function makeChoice()
{
    if(document.form1.mobileyesno[1].checked)
        $("#wanttexts").hide();
    else
        $("#wanttexts").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about something like this:

```js
jQuery(function($){
    function toggle() {
        $('#wanttexts').toggle( 
            $('[name=mobileyesno]:eq(0):checked').length == 1
        );
    }
});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

If you want `slid` effect you can do:

```
$('#mobileyesno').checked(function() {
    $('#wanttexts').slideToggle();
});
```

Otherwise:

```
$('#mobileyesno').checked(function() {
    $('#wanttexts').toggle();
});
```

Comment: $("#mobileyesno").checked is not a function when I try this

Comment: you can use .click instead :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#mobileyesno").bind("click", function() {
       $("#wanttexts").css("visibility", ($("#mobileyesno").eq(1).is(":checked") ? "hidden" : "visible"));
    });
});
```

.hide() and .show() will set the element to display:none / block - not what the OP's code does.